# Can MS Word detect single-sentence paragraphs?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

Setup: I have a long (>100 page) document and have been asked to make sure there are no single-sentence paragraphs.  While this is [not necessarily a strict rule of style](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/12986/why-one-sentence-per-paragraph-in-these-news-articles), it is a reasonable request for the context, and one that I will have to meet in future documents as well.

According to [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2008/02/05/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-sentences-and-paragraphs-in-a-word-document.aspx) 2008 source, Word was not very smart about sentence boundaries, but lots has changed since then.

An ideal answer to this would be something like "Go into File->Options->Proofing and in the "When correcting spelling and grammar in Word" section click Settings; under "Style" click the checkbox that says "Single sentence paragraphs."  However, I don't see such a checkbox in Word 2010 unless I'm missing something or it's worded differently.

There may be other ideas and good ways of accomplishing this goal out there too; if so please answer below!  Until then, it's manual review...

Comment: I think the gotcha you're facing is that there's no way for Word to know for sure if something like "I went to see Mr. Smith today." is one sentence or two.

Comment: Word could know about certain common abbreviations (e.g. Mr., Dr., etc.) and approximate the check; its accuracy would probably be comparable to many of the other grammar checks which have a lot of holes (/occasions to use the Ignore option) too.

Answer (score 2):

I dug into it a bit, and [Word can count Sentences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837481.aspx) using VBA.

For example using `MsgBox(Selection.Range.Sentences.Count)` will popup a dialog containing a count of sentences in the current selection.

It'll just count two for "I like Mr. Smith." and alike.

Probably a good starting point for a script....

Basic idea for the VBA macro:  Gather paragraphs in document as a collection, and then loop though them one at a time, counting the number of sentences in each. If it's "one", then perform some action...